# How to add listener to ul li list?

Tags: angular

How to add listener to ul li list, that is in component template?

```
<ul #list>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried:

```
@ViewChild("list", { static: false }) list: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
   list.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
}

 onKeyDown = (e) => { console.log(e); // event keydown}
```

But it does not work for me.

Comment: It would be an impoverished environment indeed that did not allow you to add a listener to *any* element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need :

**HTML :**

```
<ul #list tabindex="0">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

TS :

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  @ViewChild("list", { static: false }) list: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.list.nativeElement.focus();
    this.list.nativeElement.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
  }

  onKeyDown = (e) => { console.log(e); }

}
```

Stackblitz : [angular-add-listener-to-ul-li-list](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-add-listener-to-ul-li-list)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `ViewChild` to do that. simply use the `keydown` event.
Make sure you add tabindex to be able to focus the element.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-umck67

HTML

```
<ul tabindex=-1 (keydown)="onKeyDown($event)">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Component:

```
onKeyDown = (e) => { console.log(e);  }
```

Answer (score 1):

or you should add **nativeElement** in your example

```
 list.nativeElement.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
```

Answer (score -1):

the angular way of handling events is attaching handlers in the template, like this:

```
handleUlClick(e) {console.log(e)}
...
<ul (click)="handleUlClick($event)">
//whatever
</ul>
```

Comment: I dont need click, I need keydown event by list.

Comment: use keydown, what is the problem?

Comment: Instead click use keydown?

Comment: yes, exactly. there are "event" directives out of the box in angular that allow to handle most common events

Comment: It does not work maybe because I should set focus on ul list?

Comment: yes. elements with tabindex="0" can be focused for example